Some guidance needed (Spivak Chapter 5 Problem 20)

If $f(x)=x$ for rational $x$, and $f(x)=-x$ for irrational $x$,then
$\lim_{x \to a} f(x)$ does not exist for any $a\neq 0$

**Proof:**Intuitively, it makes sense that the limit exists at $0$ because $x$ is close to $0$ if and only if $-x$ is close to $0$. Moving on to our proof of the theorem
we use the fact that every non-empty interval of real numbers possesses both rational and irrational numbers. For some rational $x$ we have
$$0<|x-a|<\delta\Longrightarrow|x-l|<\epsilon$$
and for some irrational $x'$ we have
$$0<|x'-a|<\delta\Longrightarrow|-x'-l|<\epsilon$$
This fact is true for all $\delta$'s. The inequalities $|x-l|<\epsilon$ and $|-x'-l| <\epsilon$ imply $$l+\epsilon>x>l-\epsilon$$$$l+\epsilon>-x'>l-\epsilon$$ Since the open interval $(l+\epsilon,l-\epsilon)$ has a length of $2\epsilon$ it follow that the system of inequalities above can only be true if $|x-(-x')|<2\epsilon$. In English this means that distance between $x$ and $-x'$ is small enough to fit in the open interval. Since this is not true for $0<\epsilon<\frac{|x-(-x')|}{2}$. The limit must not exist. Q.E.D
Afterthoughts: The reason I am confused is because I don't know if my argument is sufficient to show that $l$ does not exist. I'm not entirely sure how one shows that $l$ does not exist from the epsilon delta definition of a limit. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

I can't see, in your proof, where you use the fact that $a \neq 0$. This fact should be used somewhere, because the theorem is false without this qualification. This is a big red flag for your proof.
More specifically, it seems that you begin by choosing $x, x'$ in terms of $\varepsilon$, using the density of $\Bbb{Q}$ and $\Bbb{R} \setminus \Bbb{Q}$ in $\Bbb{R}$, but end by choosing $\varepsilon$ to be between $0$ and $\frac{|x - (-x')|}{2}$, thereby choosing $\varepsilon$ based on $x, x'$. This is obviously a problem, and indeed an intractable one when $a = 0$.
This acute problem arises, I think, from a general sloppiness in quantification. Whenever you introduce a new pronumeral, it should either come from the theorem statement (which $a$ does), be accompanied by a quantifier ("for all..." or "there exists..."), or it should have an explicit definition in terms of other pronumerals and/or specific numbers. Beginning your proof with

For some rational $x$ we have
$$0<|x-a|<\delta\Longrightarrow|x-l|<\varepsilon$$

properly introduces $x$, and $a$ comes from the theorem statement, but it doesn't introduce $\varepsilon$, $\delta$, or $l$. While the choice of names follow convention, it's not clear whether you are saying this for all $\varepsilon$, for some $\varepsilon$, or for a specific $\varepsilon$ that you have neglected to mention previously. As it turns out, from your error highlighted above, you sort of mean it to be "for all $\varepsilon$", as well as "for a fixed $\varepsilon$ to be determined later". Fixing up your quantifiers forces you to be clear on this point, and makes clear these kinds of circular designations as you are writing the proof.
It seems you are going for a proof by contradiction. So, your proof should begin like this:

Suppose $a \neq 0$ and $\lim_{x \to a} f(x) = l$.

From here, you should define a specific $\varepsilon > 0$, and use the definition of a limit to get you your $\delta > 0$ (this has the quantifier $\exists$, so you know it exists, but have no control over its value). After this, you can then use the density of $\Bbb{Q}$ and $\Bbb{R} \setminus \Bbb{Q}$ to obtain your $x$ and $x'$ (so the fact that you don't know the specific $\delta > 0$ is not a problem).
Your choice of $\varepsilon > 0$ is your ace in the hole. You use it to ensure that $x$ and $-x'$ cannot be close together, which is the source of the contradiction. Choose carefully. It may help, as a hint, to define $\varepsilon$ in terms of $|a| > 0$.
Give it another try, and let me know with a comment if you need more guidance.

Let $a\neq0$ then $$\forall \epsilon>0\exists \delta>0~s.t(\forall x\in\mathbb{Q})[0<|x-a|<\delta\Longrightarrow |f(x)-l|<\epsilon]$$ but$$\forall \epsilon>0\exists \delta>0~s.t(\exists  x'\notin  \mathbb{Q})[0<|x'-a|<\delta\Longrightarrow |f(x')-l|<\epsilon]$$ The interval $0<|x-a|<\delta$ implies that for any $x$  ($x>a\oplus  x<a$) Suppose $x>a$ this implies that $x'>a$ for some $x'$. This further implies $f(x)>a \wedge f(x')<-a$ This directly implies that $|f(x)-l|<\epsilon$ is an impossibility no matter what $l$ is if we define $\epsilon=|a|$ Q.E.D.

I believe the proof above is correct I took extra care to avoid circular reasoning. And I utilized the fact that for any non empty interval of real numbers there exists both rational and irrational numbers. Your tip about substituting $\epsilon$ for $|a|$ helped me out a lot. I never knew about the idea of expressing epsilon in terms of other positive numbers. In my original post I actually tried to choose $x$ in terms of $\delta$ which I now see no sense because $\delta$ must be chosen before $x$. This fatal mistake led to my circular reasoning.

Feel free to point out any errors and thank you for your time.

@EdwardFalls This is definitely getting better. I buy the central logic of your proof, but there are still issues. I think you should expand on your contradiction, as to why, no matter the value of $l$, you get a contradiction. You know that $|f(x) - l| < |a|$ and $|f(x') - l| < |a|$. You should be able to expand these inequalities into a pair of impossible inequalities, such as $l > 0$ and $l < 0$. Also, on this topic, you seem to be implicitly assuming that $a > 0$ (otherwise $f(x) > a$ and $f(x') < -a$ is not as restrictive as you need it to be). You might need to split into two cases.

Also, I do think you need to more clearly fix the $\varepsilon$, $\delta$ and $x, x'$ that you are working with. After let $a \neq 0$, say "Let $\varepsilon = |a| > 0$. Then, there exists some $\delta$ such that$$(\forall x \in \Bbb{R})[0 < |x - a| < \delta \implies |f(x) - l| < \varepsilon = |a|].$$Fix $x \in \Bbb{Q}$ and $x' \in \Bbb{R} \setminus \Bbb{Q}$ such that $0 < |x - a| < \delta$ and $0 < |x' - a| < \delta$..." It makes it clear which $\varepsilon$ you're interested in, how your particular $\delta$ and $x, x'$ relate to it.

Let a≠0 then $$\forall \epsilon>0\exists \delta>0(\forall x\in\mathbb{R})[0<|x-a|<\delta\longrightarrow|f(x)-l|<\epsilon]$$ Let $x$ be a rational number that satisfies the above expression and $x'$ irrational. If $a>0$ then let $\epsilon=a$ so we have $|f(x)-l|<a$ and $|f(x')-l|<a$ which means $l+a>f(x)>l-a$ and  $l+a>f(x')>l-a$. We know that $f(x)>a$ for some $x$ and $f(x')<-a$ for some $x'$. Together these imply $$l>f(x)-a>0,0>f(x')+a>l$$ Which is an impossibility no matter what $l$ is

Now, suppose $a<0$ then let $\epsilon=-a$ we now have $|f(x)-l|<-a$ and $|f(x')-l<-a$ which means $l-a>f(x)>l+a$ and $l-a>f(x')>l+a$ . We know that $f(x)<a$ for some $x$ and $f(x')>-a$ for some $x'$. Together these imply $$ l>f(x')+a>0,0>f(x)-a>l$$ again, another impossibility. Therefore it follows that the limit does not exist Q.E.D

Definitely much better! I would give that proof full marks if I were your tutor. There is still one smudge that I would personally clear up, if it were my proof, for the sake of perfectionism. You say, in the first case, "We know that $f(x)>a$ for some $x$...". Instead, further up, where you let $x$ be rational, declare that $x$ is rational such that $0 < x - a < \delta$. Then $f(x) = x > a$, and $0 < |x - a| < \delta$, hence $|f(x) - l| < \varepsilon$. Similarly, also put $0 < x' - a < \delta$ before you fix $x'$. This is more elegant, rather than adding restrictions after you fix $x,x'$.

I see... thank you for your help and time.
